# Formatting print from itertools product

Tags: python, format, python-itertools

I am trying to print a list of every combination of a certain set of characters, I am using Product from itertools to do that. I have code that works for the printing of every set of characters, but, the formatting is not what i want.

Example of working code with wrong format:

```
from itertools import product

comb = product([1, "a", "."], repeat=3)

for i in comb:
    print(i)
```

The output of the code has the characters ( ' , ) which I don't want. If someone can help me get an output of what the combonation would be by its self without these characters I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Just `print(''.join(i))`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille a space in the middle would be nice

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I just can't manage to read which characters the OP doesn't want, as no example of expected output is provided;..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(*i)` should do the trick.

Explanation : the `*` unpack items from an iterable, so it is equivalent to : `print(i[0],i[1],i[2])`

Answer (score 0):

You can think of comb as being a list of all combinations as tuples.

So just unpack each item while iterating, then you can also handle seperatly:

```
for (v0, v1, v2) in comb:
    print(v0, v1, v2)
```

Result:

```
1 1 1
1 1 a
1 1 .
1 a 1
...
```